# How can I display 4 divs per row in a flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show 4 boxes per row. `box1` `box2` `box3` `box4`. I am using only flexbox method. Below is the HTML and CSS code which I am using.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent>.child {
  flex: 1 0 21%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child box1">A Child</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="box2">B Child 1</div>
    <div class="box3">B Child 2</div>
    <div class="box4">B Child 3</div>
    <div class="box5">B Child 4</div>
    <div class="box6">B Child 5</div>
    <div class="box7">B Child 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child box8"></div>
</div>
```

But `div1` and `div8` is not positioned.

Comment: i guess you wanted  flex:0 0 21%; . 21% is basis and you tell also it can grow but not shrink.

Comment: @G-Cyr i tried with 0 0 21% still same issue

Comment: what is the final result expected  ?  should the 3 childs span through 63% of parent's width or 100% ?  div inside middle child will only stack , they are not flex children here. ( which are div 1 and 8 now ? ) both rules gives different layout https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eYYaapB

Comment: yes @G-Cyr, thats what i need to do

Comment: ?? yes to what ?

Comment: @G-Cyr sorry, just checked your codePen.  It should be :-all the divs should be in a row. One row should have 4 divs. 

in my example,if you see there are 8 divs. 
So total 2 rows,  with 4 divs per row

Comment: @G-Cyr i am sorry for the confusion. I edited my question please check it now

Comment: don't be sorry, ask questions ;) . box2 to box7 are not flex children . their parent is `.child` which is not a flexbox ;)  do you have this bookmarked https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ as a reminder ?

Comment: got it, fixed it thanks :-)......

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to adjust `div` childrens' of each rows their width regarding the space they take on a row:

> You need to select each `div` and the result will be based on the average of all the `flex-grow` property numbers you set.

*Note that the property* `flex:` *is a combo for* `flex-grow`, `flex-basis` *and* `flex-shrink`.

You can read more about Flexbox using CSS on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}

.row>div:nth-child(1) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 2px;
}

.row>div:nth-child(2) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 2;
  margin: 2px;
}

.row>div:nth-child(3) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 2px;
}

.row>div:nth-child(4) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 3;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`div1` `div2` etc. are not valid HTML elements, only `div` itself is. If you want to target `div` elements individually, you should give individual classes.

For example: `<div class="div1"></div>`

Then select them in CSS using: `div.div1 {CSS code here ...}`

Comment: is turning divx into regular div  solving the issue ?  can you make a snippet ?

Comment: I put div1 just to explain the issue

Comment: it was not the issue, most of them where not flex children. ;) the second `.child`box was not a flex box. beside looks like he expected 2 rows of 4 divs . display:contents could help or rewriting html to let every children on the same level  alike https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyyEEZg