# show 4 divs in a row using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to show 4 boxes in a line using below html. So One row should have 4 boxes. I have total 8 boxes, there will be 2 rows with 4 columns.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child box1">A Child</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="box2">B Child 1</div>
    <div class="box3">B Child 2</div>
    <div class="box4">B Child 3</div>
    <div class="box5">B Child 4</div>
    <div class="box6">B Child 5</div>
    <div class="box7">B Child 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child box8">C Child</div>
</div>
```

it should be look like this

```
A-Child   Child1   Child2    Child3
Child4    Child5   Child6    C-Child
```

The css which i tried is

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.parent>.child {
  flex: 1 1 20%;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7, .box8 {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:10px solid red;
}
```

Comment: How's this question different from [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037976/how-can-i-display-4-divs-per-row-in-a-flexbox-layout)?

Comment: Can your markup change? With your current HTML, what you're trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: @disinfor my markup can't be change

Comment: @j08691 last question. I couldn't explain in a proper way

Comment: If your html cannot change then you are not going to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with `display:contents` **but** [**support**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) for that property value is poor or buggy at present.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.open {
  display: contents;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child box">A Child</div>
  <div class="child open">
    <div class="box">B Child 1</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 2</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 3</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 4</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 5</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child box">C Child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some float (yes float!)

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:25%;
  border:3px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
}

.parent {
  overflow:hidden; /* Clear float */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child box">A Child</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="box">B Child 1</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 2</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 3</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 4</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 5</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child box">C Child</div>
</div>
```

With flexbox you can *approximate* it like below:

```css
.parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.parent > .box,
.child >.box {
  height:100px;
  width:25%;
  border:3px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.child:nth-child(2) {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin:-100px 0; /* same value as height here */
}
.child:nth-child(2):before {
  content:"";
  width:25%;
}
.child:last-child {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child box">A Child</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="box">B Child 1</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 2</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 3</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 4</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 5</div>
    <div class="box">B Child 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child box">C Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I stand corrected! Nice job, Temani! I was assuming that `flex` was a requirement, but it may not have been.

Comment: @disinfor I added an idea with flexbox but it's more a hack/approximation for this particular case

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all to order based on a single parent, you need to have them all become a child of the parent.  Below is an example of how to achieve what you are looking for.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  border: 10px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">A Child</div>

  <div class="box">B Child 1</div>
  <div class="box">B Child 2</div>
  <div class="box">B Child 3</div>
  <div class="box">B Child 4</div>
  <div class="box">B Child 5</div>
  <div class="box">B Child 6</div>

  <div class="box">C Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct.  It will not layout the way you want it with your current html (hence the change to the HTML)

Comment: The code which i have is in angular, which have components kinda thing. Its html is like sample html